# Thread waiting on monitors

Tags: java, multithreading

There have been talks about performance improvement of an application I am working on in my firm. This application contains scheduled tasks which do a lot of xml parsing.At a certain hour ,when lot of such tasks are triggered off,the application becomes slow.I have been looking at the thread dump collected at one such peak hour to see what could be the problem..But being new to such kind of exercise,I could not understand much of it.Below is an excerpt from the thread dump.

```
"JMSThread(5)-7635" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000004fb5b800 nid=0x71e in Object.wait() [0x0000000048de8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00002aaabf41fe38> (a java.lang.Object)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.BoundedLinkedQueue.poll(BoundedLinkedQueue.java:253)
    - locked <0x00002aaabf41fe38> (a java.lang.Object)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor.getTask(PooledExecutor.java:723)
    at org.jboss.util.threadpool.MinPooledExecutor.getTask(MinPooledExecutor.java:106)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(PooledExecutor.java:747)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None


JMSThread(5)-7634" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000004ed5c800 nid=0x716 in Object.wait() [0x0000000044eb2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00002aaabf41fe38> (a java.lang.Object)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.BoundedLinkedQueue.poll(BoundedLinkedQueue.java:253)
    - locked <0x00002aaabf41fe38> (a java.lang.Object)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor.getTask(PooledExecutor.java:723)
    at org.jboss.util.threadpool.MinPooledExecutor.getTask(MinPooledExecutor.java:106)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(PooledExecutor.java:747)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

There are several such entries locking and waiting on a same object . Can anyone help me understand what they mean? Does this indicate any problem??

Answer (score 5):

These entries indicate that there are threads waiting for the `BoundedLinkedQueue` to become non-empty. In other words, the workers are waiting for someone to give them something to do. Without knowing more about your application's architecture, it's impossible to say whether this is indicative of a problem.

If you expect those threads to be busy, you need to look into why whoever is supposed to be adding tasks to the queue isn't adding them quickly enough to keep the workers busy.

Comment: are these threads instances of MDB's listening on the JMS queue?(Yes,my application puts in requests in a JMS Queue for asynchrounous processing)

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, there are two possible explanations: 1. Your producers are not fast enough to insert stuff into the queue, so the consumers have to wait until they get something. This would indicate that your producers slow down under certain circumstances.
2. There is something wrong with your queue, and the producers hold their locks too long while getting the tasks out of the queue.

As to the second point there might be a solution. From the look of it, you have your own implementation of a `BoundedQueue` which uses an Object to call synchronized on, to enforce thread-safety. You might want to check if you can use one of the `BlockingQueue`s provided in the `concurrency` package instead (there is a `LinkedBlockingQueue`, for example). Those queues can be bounded as well, but are designed to work well in multi-threading environments.