# Detect if there is a thread contention in a running application

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

1. I have a Java application where I am using PooledExecuter from oswego.
2. I strongly suspect that there is a thread contention in my application as irrespective of using PooledExecuter, requests are taking time = roughly no of requests * time for one request.
3. I want to gather evidence that there is definitely a thread contention.
4. Is there any way I can set some JVM parameters which show me what different threads are doing or any other way that can be useful to detect thread contention.

Comment: The library from oswego was largely merged in Java 5.0 in 2004. Have you tried the built in concurrency library as I know there have been some optimisations to the JVM to work with it?

Comment: `jvisualvam` displays nicely what each thread is doing.

Comment: +1 for jvisualvm (it comes with JDK) and Yourkit profiler is commercial tool I had good experience with.

Comment: Also make sure that you have configured pool size > 1.

Answer (score 2):

From your description it sounds like you have a resource which is single threaded and you code isn't able to use multiple threads efficiently.  You should be able to see this by taking a thread dump while this is happening (a few times) You should see one thread doing "real" work, and all the other thread in the pool waiting for something or idle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338131/thread-waiting-on-monitors is related (shows dumps and explanations)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of jvm options that can tell you this, I would attach a profiler to it and see if the threads are contending (blocked / waiting) lots, and then see which locks they are contending for.